# NET6.0 FTP server networking issue on Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-6.0, alpine-linux, streamwriter, ftp-server

I’m developing a `NET 6.0 FTP server` as part of a functionality to load the firmware of a hardware device. I need to have it inside a Docker container but I’m unable to make it work on that environment when it works perfectly when I execute it as a regular executable. It seems to be something related to docker networking but I can’t figure it out what it is.

This is the Dockerfile for the container, that is based on Alpine (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine`), with some additions from the default Dockerfile created by Visual Studio:

```bash
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
  
RUN apk add openrc --no-cache

ENV MUSL_LOCALE_DEPS cmake make musl-dev gcc gettext-dev libintl 
ENV MUSL_LOCPATH /usr/share/i18n/locales/musl

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    $MUSL_LOCALE_DEPS \
    && wget https://gitlab.com/rilian-la-te/musl-locales/-/archive/master/musl-locales-master.zip \
    && unzip musl-locales-master.zip \
      && cd musl-locales-master \
      && cmake -DLOCALE_PROFILE=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr . && make && make install \
      && cd .. && rm -r musl-locales-master

RUN apk add icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["nuget.config", "."]
COPY ["CONTAINERS/Project1/Project1.csproj", "CONTAINERS/Project/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CONTAINERS/Project1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CONTAINERS/Project1"
RUN dotnet build "Project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project1.dll"]
```

The Docker run parameters are these

```bash
-p 20:20 -p 21000-22000:21000-22000
```

where `20` is the control port for FTP, it is the port used by that external hardware device and cannot be modified by me, and `21000-22000` is the range for FTP passive mode.

The FTP server code is quite simple and it works nice directly being executed in the host machine:

```
public class FtpServer : IDisposable
{
    ...
    
    public ErrorCode Start(string ip, int port, string basepath, string user, string password, int minPassivePort = 0, int maxPassivePort = 0)
    {
        ErrorCode retVal = ErrorCode.Success;

        _basepath = basepath;

        _user = user;

        _password = password;

        PassivePortMin = minPassivePort;
        PassivePortMax = maxPassivePort;

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;

        _localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

        _listener = new TcpListener(_localEndPoint);

        _listening = true;

        _activeConnections = new List<ClientConnection>();

        try
        {
            _listener.Start();

            LocalEndpoint = ((IPEndPoint)_listener.LocalEndpoint).Address.ToString();

            _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAcceptTcpClient, _listener);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error starting FTP server", ex);

            retVal = ErrorCode.ConnectionFailure;
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    private void HandleAcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (_listening)
        {
            TcpClient client = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);

            _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAcceptTcpClient, _listener);

            ClientConnection connection = new ClientConnection(client, _user, _password, _basepath);

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(connection.HandleClient, client);
        }
    }

public class ClientConnection
{
        public ClientConnection(TcpClient client, string username, string password, string basepath)
    {
        
        _controlClient = client;

        _currentUser = new User
        {
            Username = username,
            Password = password,
            HomeDir = basepath
        };

        _validCommands = new List<string>();
    }

    public void HandleClient(object obj)
    {
        //  bool error = false;

        try
        {
            _remoteEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)_controlClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;

            _clientIP = _remoteEndPoint.Address.ToString();

            _controlStream = _controlClient.GetStream();

            _controlReader = new StreamReader(_controlStream);
            _controlWriter = new StreamWriter(_controlStream);
            
            _controlWriter.WriteLine("220 Service Ready.");
            _controlWriter.Flush();

            _validCommands.AddRange(new string[] { "AUTH", "USER", "PASS", "QUIT", "HELP", "NOOP" });

            string line;

            _dataClient = new TcpClient();

            string renameFrom = null;

            while ((line = _controlReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string response = null;

                string[] command = line.Split(' ');

                string cmd = command[0].ToUpperInvariant();
                string arguments = command.Length > 1 ? line.Substring(command[0].Length + 1) : null;

                if (arguments != null && arguments.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    arguments = null;
                }

                if (!_validCommands.Contains(cmd))
                {
                    response = CheckUser();
                }

                if (cmd != "RNTO")
                {
                    renameFrom = null;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(cmd + " " + arguments);

                if (response == null)
                {
                    switch (cmd)
                    {

                        default:
                            response = "502 Command not implemented";
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (_controlClient == null || !_controlClient.Connected)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                    {
                        _controlWriter.WriteLine(response);
                        _controlWriter.Flush();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(response);

                    if (response.StartsWith("221"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error sending command", ex);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        Dispose();
    }
```

}

The issue seems to be located in `_controlWriter`, it seems that anything is blocking the response to the device (`220` Service Ready) or maybe the frame is not being redirected to the right network interface, because nothing is read from `_controlReader`. As I mentioned earlier, this exact same code works perfectly when I execute it in the host machine, outside Docker container, that's the reason why I think it could be something related to Docker networking.

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was something related to carriage return. Since docker container used a Linux based image, the carriage return was \n and the device expected \r\n.

Thanks to everyone who took a look at this.